# Adjust <p> width on bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello friends I have a problem with bootstrap and the `<p>` tag. When I add some big text in the `<p>` tag, it doesn't adjust to the 6 column that I define, it stays continuous to the right of the page taking up all space.

How could I make the text within the `<p>` tag always take the first 6 colums?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class='container'>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-6'>
    <h2 class='text'>text</h2>
    <hr>
    <h4 class='text-warning'>Title</h4>
    <p>text content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: on which screen are you getting it as taking up all of the width? I mean iPad, desktop or mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this as a custom style and it'll wrap at your defined column size.

```
p{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Check it out [here](http://www.bootply.com/EMSehwi6qg).

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you close all your `<div>` tags.

And then make sure you are displaying the device you need. The class `col-sm-6` is for tabelt view. If you want 6 columns on every device add these classes aswell: `col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6`.

Due to the fact that bootstrap is mobile-first it would be enough to add only the rule `col-xs-6`, so it will have 6 columns on every device.

To learn more about the grid and the breakpoints visit:
[Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) and scroll to Grid options

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.